# EXE to APK converter

Tags: windows, android, code-conversion

I need a simple tool for android smartphones which converts the
computer files which are in the EXE format to the APK which is an android file format so the I can run those apps on my android smartphone as well.

Comment: It probably will not be able to run complex programs such as LibreOffice or 3D games, but for very basic programs (for instance command line) that sounds feasible. It would probably rely on an emulator (Wine can run on Android).

Comment: Sure, it's possible. You just need some tool which packages [that JavaScript](https://copy.sh/v86/?profile=windows98) with your EXE and a browser into an APK and then run int on Android. *argh!* It's so crazy how powerful computers are today. @NicolasRaoul